# SXA Issue displaying fields with new rendering

Tags: sxa, experience-editor, presentation

**Environment details**: Sitecore 9.0.2 + SXA 1.7.1

**What I have done till now**:
I followed the  steps provided at https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/copy-and-customize-a-rendering.html

While cloning, I had selected the option to duplicate the items (datasource/view) wherever applicable.
I changed the css class to 'Promo' from 'Promo-copy' to keep it in sync with rendering 'Promo'.

I am able to find the new rendering in the toolbox.

So, my rendering(PromoTest) is the duplicate of the promotion rendering. I also have a template of the same name(PromoTest) and the rendering is pointing to the new template.
On this new template PromoTest, I have created an item Promo1.

I opened a partial rendering in the experience editor and added my new rendering 'PromoTest' to the 'main' placeholder.

**Issue**: The values in the fields of 'Item1' are not getting rendered.

Am I missing something? Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Rendering variant definition? Do you have it on your site? Is it assigned to your rendering? Check if field names match with your fields names from data source

Comment: Did you set the datasource to the correct item?

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak: Thanks for pointing it out. I was under impression that default one will be applied even if no variant is created. Please provide your comment as the answer. So, I can accept the same. Can you please help me with one more issue? I have added this rendering to a few styles under presentation but I am not getting the styles option in experience editor.

Comment: @Abhishek Please create a new question for styles problem. It will be easier for others to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that everything is OK with *rendering variant* definition.

- check if it's present in your site,
- check if your rendering has assigned proper variant,
- make sure that field names in RV definition match with those from data source